# Duplicity specified archive directory does not exist

Tags: duplicity

When executing: `duplicity --force remove-older-than 10D file:///fullSystemBackup/`

Produces an error of: `Specified archive directory '/home/bitnami/.cache/duplicity/abcxyz' does not exist, or is not a directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was I ran the command with a different user as to when I made a backup with Duplicity.